# Wordpress - Need to combine/search array [0]->slug, [1]->slug, etc within foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, metadata, custom-taxonomy

In this particular code, I have a `<select multiple="multiple">` field (using `select2.js`) in my admin backend within a custom post type with custom taxonomies. Everything in that area is working as expected. I'm having issues with displaying the multiple selected choices as I don't know how to set up the array correctly and/or if the code is correct.

I have included `var_dump()` as it shows that both values have saved, but only the first is showing. I know this is because of the code `(( $breed->slug == $select_breed[0]->slug ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' )` but I don't know how to do the same line of code for eg: `$select_breed[ALL/ANY]->slug` as sometimes they may select 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 different values. Some assistance with this line of code would be most appreciated!

_N.B. With the assistance of @CBroe, I have incorporated `array_column()` and `in_array()` to formulate a working code. Any other suggestions are welcome. I have included the results as an answer.

**CODE**

```
<?php
/**
 * Pet Breed
 */         
$breed_args = get_terms( array (
    'taxonomy' => 'breed_taxonomy',
    'hide_empty' => false
));

$select_breed = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'breed_taxonomy' );
?>
<div class="section group">
    <div class="col full">
        <label for="pet_breed"><strong><?php _e( 'Pet Breed', 'audar_pets' ); ?> <abbr class="required" >*</abbr></strong><br />
        <select id="pet_breed" class="taxonomy-select" name="pet_breed[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;" required="required" required >
            <option></option>
            <?php
            if ( !empty( $breed_args ) ) :

                foreach( $breed_args as $breed ) :

                    echo '<option value="' . $breed->slug . '" ' . (( $breed->slug == $select_breed[0]->slug ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ) . ' >' . $breed->name . '</option>';

                endforeach;

            endif;
            ?>
        </select>
        </label>
        <?php
        $pet_breed = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'breed_taxonomy' );
        var_dump( $pet_breed );
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SAVE**

```
wp_set_post_terms( get_the_ID(), $_POST['pet_breed'], 'breed_taxonomy', false );
```

**RESULTS OF VAR_DUMP( $PET_BREED )**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(WP_Term)#16459 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(153)
    ["name"]=>
    string(19) "German Shepherd Dog"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(19) "german-shepherd-dog"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(153)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(14) "breed_taxonomy"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(WP_Term)#16464 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(154)
    ["name"]=>
    string(27) "German Short-Haired Pointer"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(27) "german-short-haired-pointer"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(154)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(14) "breed_taxonomy"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(0)
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
}
```

Comment: Well you would have to loop over `$select_breed`, and compare your breed’s slug to each selected slug individually … set a flag if you find a match, and then based on that decide whether to output `selected`, or not. Or you make this a little easier - and extract all the slug values from `$select_breed` using `array_column`. Once you have a “flat” array that contains only the selected slugs as strings, you can then simply use `in_array` to perform the check, and don’t need to write a loop or anything like that yourself.

Comment: Thankyou i was considering a count() and while() option but I didnt know how to add the while to the foreach loop. How would you extract the slug values? I'll look into array_column. If you could provide a basic example I will give it a try! Thanks for your comment.

Comment: `$slugs = array_column($select_breed, 'slug');` should do the trick. (Use var_dump to verify, $slugs should contain only the slug values as items now.)

Comment: Thankyou. It's late here. I'll implement it as soon as I can and reply accordingly.

Comment: @CBroe - Thank-you for your help. I looked into your `array_column()` suggestion, and also included `in_array()`. You put me on the right path so a mark-up is definately warranted. Please have a look at my revised question for the solution.

Comment: Glad it worked. Could you make this an actual answer though, please? To keep with the Q&A format if this site ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

I have incorporated array_column() and in_array() to formulate a working code as you can see below. The array_column() finds the 'slug', then the in_array() checks the slug in the get_terms() and the array_column() within the foreach().

**WORKING CODE**

```
<?php 
/**
 * Pet Breed
 */         
$breed_args = get_terms( array (
    'taxonomy' => 'breed_taxonomy',
    'hide_empty' => false
));

$select_breed = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'breed_taxonomy' );
$select_breed_slug = array_column( $select_breed, 'slug' ); // Thanks @CBroe
?>
<div class="section group">
    <div class="col full">
        <label for="pet_breed"><strong><?php _e( 'Pet Breed', 'audar_pets' ); ?> <abbr class="required" >*</abbr></strong><br />
        <select id="pet_breed" class="taxonomy-select" name="pet_breed[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;" required="required" required >
            <option></option>
            <?php
                if ( !empty( $breed_args ) ) :

                    foreach ( $breed_args as $breed ) :

                        echo '<option value="' . $breed->slug . '" ' . ( $breed->slug == in_array( $breed->slug, $select_breed_slug ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ) . ' >' . $breed->name . '</option>'; // Additional Code (in_array())

                    endforeach;

                endif;
            ?>
        </select>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it